# How does the JMicrodata function work in Joomla?

Tags: joomla, microdata

I read this officail Joomla article about Microdata: http://docs.joomla.org/Microdata

I tried put this `meta` element in the `head` section of my Joomla website:

```
<meta itemprop="name" content="title of your content">
```

By this code:

```
$scope="itemprop";
$property="name";
$content="title";

JMicrodata::htmlMeta($content, $property, $scope = '', $inverse = false);
```

But no success! Can somebody tell me whats the wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Solutions

To add this **meta** tag in you `<head>` section of a Joomla website:

```
<meta itemprop="name" content="title of your content">
```

You can use one of the following solutions

1) Add this code in the `<head>` section:

```
echo JMicrodata::htmlMeta($content = 'title', $property = 'name');
```

2) In whatever part of your code/file you want:

```
$microdata = JMicrodata::htmlMeta($content = 'title', $property = 'name');
$document  = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addCustomTag($microdata);
```

---

## Documentation help

`JMicrodata::htmlMeta()` is used for output microdata semantics in a meta tag, **this method does not add the meta tag in the** `<head>` **section**.

I see you use `$scope="itemprop"`, which is wrong, the **scope** is used to specify the *Type* of microdata, here you can find the full list of the available *Types* http://schema.org/docs/full.html

I suggest you to use an instance of `JMicrodata`, this way you don't need to worry that microdata is displayed properly.

```
$microdata = new JMicrodata('Article');
echo $microdata->content('title')->property('name')->display('meta');
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `<head>` section add

```
<?php 
$property="name";
$content="title";
echo JMicrodata::htmlMeta($content, $property, '', false);
 ?>
```

That will definitely get you the metadata.

Elsewhere if you did

```
$property="name";
$content="title";
$microdata = JMicrodata::htmlMeta($content, $property, '', false);
$document  = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addCustomTag($microdata);
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks.I'm on joomla 3.2.2 and I think it dosen't support it so I have to build my own function. :)

Comment: It supports it just fine but it's not built in yet, that is right, you have to instantiate your own to really use the whole thing.